# chrome space at bottom of page, not locally though

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Chrome (osx 10.7.4) I am getting a blank space at the bottom of my page http://presstube.com/vandalized-notes/

I would normally assume that it is just some whacked out css, but I've noticed 3 strange things in my hunting.

1. this only happens online.. locally the space is not there! wtf?
2. when i use the inspector it looks like the space is taking place outside the html
3. when I scroll all the way to the bottom, then reload, the browser's scroll is reset just above that space.

here is a screenshot of it online:
[image: the space at the bottom of the page, only showing in chrome online]

here is a screenshot of it locally:
[image]

If anyone can shed some light I'd appreciate it!

thanks,-j

Comment: Please add a screenshot with space. I cannot see any space

Comment: added those shots, of it happening live, and one of it not happening locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ughhh! after much wasted time I found out that it was some malware Chrome extensions that had snuck in. something call "quick-save".

If you're having this, go look in your chrome extensions and look for anything seedy and trash it.

The telltale sign was that in my console I had lots of suspicious looking js activity going on. I googled one of the servers it was trying to access and found a some chrome documentation warning of the se nasty extensions.

Hope that helps someone else who is ripping apart their perfectly good html/css in search of weird mystery spaces in their layout!

Comment: I was experiencing this same problem with Windows Chrome and Apple Safari. I tried your solution by turning off my Extensions one-by-one and established it was an Extension named "Save As" that was the culprit. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your class `.footy` has `padding-bottom` set to `80px`. Change this to change the space at the bottom.

Comment: thanks, but that's not the space I was talking about. that's the space that I want : ) It's the white strip across the bottom that's showing up only when I view it online, but not locally. I've added some screenshots so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Well then I am not seeing that line across the bottom on Chrome. I am using Chrome on OSX 10.6.8